# How can I remove "Ubuntu Netbook Edition" option from the GDM session menu?

Tags: 10.10, unity, gdm

I was trying out Unity and then I uninstalled it but there is still an `Ubuntu Netbook Edition` option in the GDM session list. Accidentally clicking on that causes the user to log in to a broken desktop. How can I remove it from the list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to the Ubuntu Software Center and use the search box in the upper right corner. Search for ubuntu-netbook and remove the packages `ubuntu-netbook` and `ubuntu-netbook-default-settings`.

Comment: To which I'll add be sure to check which session manager your login screen is using. I followed this advice and was greeted with a live but empty X display. It was only after seeing hhlp's answer that I noticed that GDM was still selecting Netbook session which - of course - couldn't run since it wasn't installed. Thanks to all three of you for helping me out of a white screen with cursor.

Comment: Correction: removing `ubuntu-netbook-default-settings` does the trick, but I'll leave my prior comment in case someone else only does the removal half-way and sees the same as I did.

Answer (score 3):

The list is populated by looking at the contents of the `/usr/share/xsessions` directory. In here you’ll find files with the `.desktop` extension (extension hidden in some file managers, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>). As these files are in a system folder, you will need root privileges to change or delete them.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading from Ubuntu 10.10 Lucid Lynx (10.10) Netbook Edition to Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal, the upgrade process does not remove the ubuntu-netbook and ubuntu-netbook-default-settings packages. Subsequent login attempts result in a broken desktop being displayed with background but no panels whatsoever.

In order to fix this problem, press CTRL+ALT+DEL and select the Restart option. When logging in after restart, after selecting a username, select Ubuntu session option from the drop-down box in the bottom bar. This will start the Natty's default session with Unity.

Next, run the following command in a Terminal window in order to remove the non-working option from the session list.

> sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-netbook ubuntu-netbook-default-settings