# Uninstall Unity, rewind to old UNR interface, keeping 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, unity, ubuntu-netbook

I've upograded 10.04 to 10.10 on my netbook. The unity interface doesn't work for me, it just gets in the way. I can change the gdm choice at boot to put me into good ol' gnome, which is better than unity but not nearly as nice as the 10.04 UNR. How do I install the UNR interface on top of 10.10? Is there a how to - can't see anything useful on the ubuntu site, everyone there is trying to pretend that unity is great.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10090/how-can-i-remove-ubuntu-netbook-edition-option-from-the-gdm-session-menu/10096#10096

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe, gersoid wants the old UNR not a normal desktop. Is that right?

Comment: correct. I can rewind to the normal GNOME desktop fairly easily, I want the 10.04 UNR interface back, I liked that a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can install the `ubuntu-netbook-efl` and `ubuntu-netbook-efl-default-settings` packages (using `apt-get` or the Software Center) to get one of the 2 versions of the old netbook interface (the one that doesn't require 3D support).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is small mistake in JanC reply. Correct packages are:

- `ubuntu-netbook-efl-default-settings`
- `netbook-launcher-efl`

Then logout and select 2d session.

Answer (score 0):

According to [chris](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10090/how-can-i-remove-ubuntu-netbook-edition-option-from-the-gdm-session-menu/10096#10096) as posted here,

> Go to the Ubuntu Software Center and
>   use the search box in the upper right
>   corner. Search for "ubuntu-netbook"
>   and remove the packages ubuntu-netbook
>   and ubuntu-netbook-default-settings.

Or less graphically:

```
 sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-netbook ubuntu-netbook-default-settings
```

worked for me. And I concur, Unity was not ready enough for me.

Comment: If I do that do I just go back to gnome (which I can do anyway) or do I get the 10.04 UNR look+feel?

Comment: It made it like I never installed Unity and everything looked, felt, and worked like vanilla Lucid/Maverick.

Comment: Ok will try thks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `sudo apt-get purge unity*` on top of that, and you'll be rid of it all ;)