# Mutter slows down my system

Tags: performance, mutter

My Ubuntu (10.10, netbook remix, unity) almost freezes from time to time. As far as I've investigated, the problem is with `mutter`. Then I run

```
pkill mutter
```

it restarts window manager and system becomes fast again.

Mutter eats like ~15-20% of my memory (2 gb).

What can I do about it? I just hate the situation. Maybe I should just add this command (`pkill mutter`) to `crontab` or something

Answer (score 2):

Unity in Ubuntu 10.10 doesn't run very well on certain systems and unfortunately, there's nothing you can do about it. Personally, I'd just use Ubuntu 10.04 with the old netbook interface, and wait for Ubuntu 11.04 with Unity/Compiz, which is a major step forward performance-wise.

Edit: Maybe you can install the old netbook interface in 10.10. I haven't tried this, but here's a question covering this topic: [Uninstall Unity, rewind to old UNR interface, keeping 10.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11322/uninstall-unity-rewind-to-old-unr-interface-keeping-10-10)

Comment: maybe I can try 11.04 right now? I don't really want to reinstall the system twice. Or it's too unreliable?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 is currently in development (in an alpha stage) and not recommended for use on productive systems. It might work but it might as well eat your kittens. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The most effective command I have found to restart/refresh mutter on 10.10 is:

```
naaman@naaman-XPS-M1330:~$ mutter-message restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing Unity 2D is also an option if you want something quicker (though it is still a bit unfinished):

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop)