# Can I install  UNR in 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-netbook

I would love to use UNR instead of unity, I think it's much better. I first found it in 10.04 netbook but I don't want to do a fresh install of that it's way to much work.

I have a new problem, I can't choose what interface I want like, unity, UNR or normal desktop (on the log in screen). It may be sorted in the final release but, now it's a big problem.

Everything works now, and it's stable, big thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tried it, but you can install `netbook-launcher-efl`, which should look like this:

[image]

I don't know if the package still exists on Natty, but in Maverick it does.

Comment: @Alvar You need to logout and then select something like "Ubuntu netbook remix" at the login prompt (Where it normally says "Ubuntu")

Comment: well I can't even select normal desktop mode! how do I do it? everything is wrong in natty (or different)

Comment: aaaah, it's very buggy this, I could log in and see the Beautiful UNR desktop and when I opened the system monitor everything was a normal desktop again. sad hope it becomes more stable in the final release of 11.04.

Comment: When I added some favorites everyting worked! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a [Natty Narwhal](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/netbook-launcher-efl) package from the Launchpad [Netbook Launcher EFL](https://launchpad.net/launch-lite-proj) project (which is not identical to the Netbook Launcher that came with the 9.10 a, 10.04 UNR). See also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11322/uninstall-unity-rewind-to-old-unr-interface-keeping-10-10). I have not tested this, mainly because I am very happy with Unity.

Comment: This helped but i just needed the first package.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer to my problem. simply edit the default. I really hope it works now.

[image]