# How do I switch to the Classic GNOME Desktop?

Tags: 11.04, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

How can I setup the Natty Classic Desktop to be "really" classic? I want to have the menus in the application window and I want to have the normal Gnome Menu with Applications, Places and System.

Any way to get that?