# Will Unity work with a video card without 3D support?

Tags: unity, unity-2d

I am currently running Ubuntu 10.10. The Unity Netbook interface seems to fail on my laptop because it has an unsupported video card (one of the Radeon ones).

- Will I have a problem with I upgrade to 11.04 where Unity is default?
- Can I just switch it back to a different interface (the one that is currently default on 10.04)?

Answer (score 4):

In 11.04, if the graphic card can not support 3D, and consequently Compiz, it will fallback to Classic mode, which you can try out by selecting it from the dropdown menu when you log in.

- [How do I switch to the Classic GNOME Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28050/i-want-to-use-the-classic-desktop-with-classic-menus-and-classic-gnome-menu-but)

or you can install the Unity 2D environment, which will be the default Unity UI for ARM-based systems:

- [How do I install and switch to the Unity 2D desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop)

Comment: This is not true - the classic desktop will be used not Unity 2D. Unity 2D is planned for use in future versions.

Comment: I thought it had been stated it would ship with 11.04

Comment: Well it uses the classic desktop as the fallback currently (as tested in VirtualBox) so I will take that as the truth unless you can find a reliable source that says otherwise.

Comment: http://generaldatasecurity.com/software/2011/01/15/ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal-will-ship-with-2d-version-of-unity-for-older-and-weaker-computers/

Answer (score 1):

I think if you jump to 11.04 and it does not support the Unity it'll fallback to the Classic Desktop. I have a netbook (Acer + Atom) in here that runs Unity on the 10.10 pretty well, but does not go that well with the Classic Desktop.