# How can I find out if I am running Unity 3d or 2d?

Tags: 11.04, unity, unity-2d

I am running a Natty Beta 2 LiveCD and I realized that by default I booted right into one of the Unity desktop environments. I then looked into the additional drivers app to find that I am not running the usual ATI proprietary graphics driver ubuntu needs to run at full capacity. Based on that I would assume that I am running 2d but I don't know, how do I find that out for myself?

Comment: More answers here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unity 2D is not a default in 11.04 - it will be in 11.10.  Until then, the 11.04 live CD will come with two choices - Unity 3D or Gnome 2.  If you see the "launcher-bar" on the left hand side of the screen, you are running Unity using the open-source ATI driver.

You [can switch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28050/how-do-i-use-use-the-classic-gnome-desktop) between the two types by logging out and choosing the "Session" type at the bottom of the screen.

If you wish to try Unity 2D [look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop).

Answer (score 3):

I just run this command in a terminal window:

```
ps -ef | grep unity
```

I see "unity-2d-launcher" in the list of running processes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you'd tell what you're running at a given moment.  The login screen allows you to select which environment to use for a session.

If you just want to know if the unity 2D package is installed, you could try this at a terminal:

```
aptitude search ~dunity | grep 2d
```

If the packages listed have a "i" on the far left next to them, that means Unity 2D is installed.  If instead there is a "p" or "c", then it's not and therefore you are using the full Unity.