# How do I change my desktop back to the way it was in 10.10 from Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use use the Classic GNOME Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28050/how-do-i-use-use-the-classic-gnome-desktop)

How do I change my desktop back to the way it was in Ubuntu 10.10? I don't like the Unity interface.

Answer (score 5):

Logout and choose Ubuntu Classic from the Session drop-down at the bottom.

Remember, Gnome3 and Unity is the "future".  If you like the Gnome2 style, suggest you start looking at XFCE as your desktop in the next year or so.

Answer (score 0):

Before you type your password at the login screen, Go down the bottom and select "Ubuntu Classic" where "Ubuntu Desktop" was.

Comment: The answer is almost identical to that of fossfreedom

Comment: I typed it just before his appeared on my screen, I would have beaten him if I didn't have to login.