# How to switch back to classic mode?

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I switch to the Classic GNOME Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28050/how-do-i-switch-to-the-classic-gnome-desktop)
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

I don't like both of Unity and Gnome 3, but I can't find the classic one either, after installed Gnome 3.

The only choices are:

```
Fluxbox
Gnome shell
Recovery mode
User defined session
```

So how to get back the classic session?