# Launcher does not display any items

Tags: unity, nvidia, icons

My desktop does not display icons in Unity 3D, Compiz works 100%, except for Unity.

My video card is a Geforce FX 5200 (nvidia-173).

See the picture

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: This is a known bug. See this link for more information: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/762478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As htorque said, it looks like there is [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/762478) in the drivers for the GeForce FX.

Until that bug is fixed, you can either [use Unity 2D](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop) or [use Classic Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28050/how-do-i-use-use-the-classic-gnome-desktop).