# Getting 10.04 LTS interface on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, unity, gui, interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use use the Classic GNOME Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28050/how-do-i-use-use-the-classic-gnome-desktop)

I've recently upgraded my netbook to Ubuntu 11.04 and the new GUI interface looks somewhat nice (I specially enjoy the workspace switcher and the new applications finder) but I'm missing some widgets I had on my (now gone) taskbar, widgets like limiting the CPU usage or load monitor that I have no idea how to get back.

So, how can I use those widgets in this new interface (Unity, I think)? If that isn't possible how can I revert to the old interface without downgrading the operating system?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sure this has been covered at least a few times here on Ask Ubuntu. A quick search on here or Google would have given you the answer straight away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To revert to the classic interface used in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, you can choose the "Ubuntu Classic" session when you log in.  At the login screen, double-click on your name.  At that point, the bottom of the screen will have several options you can set before you log in.  Where it says "Ubuntu", click there and choose "Ubuntu Classic" instead.  It should remember this setting each time you log in until you change it again in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Just log in to Ubuntu Classic from the login screen.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [List of Application indicators](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators?s=1ccf7c8a-221e-4d01-bfa9-4939370ecfd3)