# Remove unity from 11.04

Tags: 11.04, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I switch to the Classic GNOME Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28050/how-do-i-switch-to-the-classic-gnome-desktop)

So, I just upgraded to 11.04 (from 10.10), and really cannot stand the unity interface.

Is there any way to go back to the 10.10 style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try logging into the "Ubuntu Classic" environment by selecting said option AFTER clicking your username on the login screen, but before logging in.

Comment: No problem, I will add that as plans stand currently, this option will be REMOVED in Oneiric. The classic session is meant as a fallback for those without hardware compatibility for compiz and will be replaced by the less intensive Unity2D in Oneiric. Classic Gnome (that I know of) will no longer be available in the repos.

Comment: @ShroudedCloud that is really a disappointment.

Comment: @ShroudedCloud: Careful there.  As far as I know, the session is to be removed from the default CD, but that doesn't mean removing it from the repository.  We normally don't remove things from the repository when they stop being available by default.

Comment: @TM: But in case you miss classic GNOME, you might consider GNOME Shell (as it is more productive and customizable than Unity as of now) which will be in official repositories of Oneiric, as we love Ubuntu but I feel that Unity has terrible Usability issues that we just want to get rid of it in case it doesn't improve in the future versions.

Comment: @ShroudedCloud, That's very bad news.  @TM, besides, even if you opt out of Unity in Natty, there are frequent freezes of the UI and all you can do is press the power button. Looks like it's time to get out of Ubuntu altogether it seems.

Comment: It hasn't been the smoothest ride IMHO. @Alain: 'Ubuntu Classic' didn't work on my hardware that well either. Unity. Well, I should keep my mouth shut I guess. It is free after all.

Comment: @Colin Watson True, however, maintaining GNOME 2 (which is what he asked for as well as the GNOME 3 files would likely be too hard to pull off. Yes, there is a chance. But we don't exactly see GNOME 1 offerings anymore.

Comment: @ShroudedCloud Gnome 3's official Fallback is Gnome Panel 3 which is a newer version of the Gnome 2 interface, tweaked to resemble Gnome Shell a bit more. The panel isn't dead yet.