# when working in Ubuntu it crashes into TTY

Tags: 11.04, unity, tty

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 with the default Unity.  I have had it crash into the TTY command prompt (black screen) from just about any program I am using (not program specific).  When it goes into the TTY, I can login in and get to a command prompt, but am unable to return to the GUI.  I am left with no alternative but to use the "sudo reboot" command to reboot the HP Laptop Pavilion dv9000.  Any one having this problem?  I've used 10.04 & 10.10 without any such problem.

Comment: Sounds like graphics card driver problem, however last X server crashes reported for GeForce Go 7600 I've found [were in 2009](http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=136649). First, make sure you use a binary driver using Additional Drivers application (`jockey-gtk`). Then we could use a log file - when the crash occurs, login to command line and run `cp /var/log/Xorg.0.log ~/` - then reboot and post contents of `Xorg.0.log` file in your home directory to http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: I pasted the results of the Xorg.0.log hope this hels

Comment: What's the link, please?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/633132/

Comment: Thanks. There is current bugreport on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/681945 - you could try switching to non-accelerated desktop (*Ubuntu Classic (no effects)* on login screen) just to see, if it helps.

Comment: actually I installed Unity 2D and it seems to have solved the problem.  Or at least it hasn't crashed as of yet.  If this is a bug in Natty, are they going to fix it?  How do I find out if they are doing something about this?

Comment: Follow the bug report I've mentioned in my previous comment. One more question though - have you installed Natty "from scratch" or have you upgraded to it from the previous version of Ubuntu?

Comment: natty from scratch.  I've noticed several other differences in my install from what I read on this blog as to cures for other's issues, i.e. if i right click on desktop, noting happens.  Yet I read this morning about a procedure to all a unity launcher via right click on the desktop.  I have several other small issue's, but not for here.  Thanks

Comment: When it dropped you to TTY, did it show any errors in the `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` TTY about anything?  If so, what was the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sudo service gdm restart` to get the login screen back. If you use "ps ax grep gnome-session", then you will see if you're still logged in, or if the session has ended. You might want to pay attention and see if you get two gnome-sessions when you log back in. If that's the case, then you can use `killall -u username gnome-session` to end the old one. (You don't need sudo for that, and replace "username" with your actual username).

But if this happens frequently, then you might want to [switch to the Ubuntu Classic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28050/how-do-i-switch-to-the-classic-gnome-desktop) session from the login screen, or [install Unity 2D](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-the-unity-2d-desktop) from the archives.

Comment: It happened again.  More info below: