# Ubuntu 11.04 with Gnome 2?

Tags: 11.04, unity, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I switch to the Classic GNOME Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28050/how-do-i-switch-to-the-classic-gnome-desktop)

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04 and I was not happy with the default user interface (Unity).

What options I have if I don't want to use this UI as I prefer Windows-like Gnome 2 from previous Ubuntu versions? Can I install Gnome 2 on 11.04?

Is Gnome 3 similar to Gnome 2 or is it experimental as Unity? What is the relationship between Gnome 3 and Gnome Shell?

I am really confused by all these options. I just want to have classic taskbars and menus like the ones that are in Gnome 2/Windows/Mac OS X.

Comment: 11.04 has gnome 2 installed: log out, select user and at the bottom choose 'gnome classic'.

Answer (score 1):

In 11.04 you still have the option do use the old UI. Install, log out, log in - choose ubuntu classic and you have the standard UI. In 11.10 this option will no longer be available in the 700 MB package.

Comment: Does that mean, I can download the 11.10 dvd and it will have an ubuntu classic option ?

Comment: Actually I don't know. However, I doubt it as Gnome is moving to Gnome 3. And Ubuntu will not put the Gnome desktop in their standard package. But may be somebody will provide the ubuntu classic like sombody did with UNE UI for 11.04 see www.omgubuntu.co.uk/tag/une/