# 10.04 Ubuntu Desktop on Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, 10.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I switch to the Classic GNOME Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28050/how-do-i-switch-to-the-classic-gnome-desktop)

question is this. Is there a way I can install the Ubuntu Desktop version from say 10.04 or 10.10 into Ubuntu 11.04? I know you used to be able to do

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

in the the terminal but can you do that now in 11.04? I kinda like Unity and the bar on the left but it is a tad annoying sometimes when I minimize applications etc. If I can install the old Ubuntu Desktop that'd be great. Thanks for any and all help/ideas!

Comment: Log out choose ubuntu classic.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28050/how-do-i-switch-to-the-classic-gnome-desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the Ubuntu Classic desktop from your login screen. Or you can goto "Login Screen" settings and make the Ubuntu Classic the default choice. To run "Login Screen" settings press `Alt+F2` and type `gdmsetup`.

Though the Ubuntu Classic desktop is only available in Ubuntu 11.04 but it will not be there in Ubuntu 11.10.

Mark have already [mentioned](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/739812/comments/5) about that Ubuntu Classic fallback will not be part of Oneiric,

> "We made very good progress on a11y in Natty, but will miss the goal
>   of perfect a11y. We'll nail it in Oneiric. That's OK, because we have
>   the Classic desktop fallback in Natty, but will not in Oneiric."

Comment: Yeah thanks lol found that after I posted the question...