# How do I restore the old look of Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: 11.04, gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I switch to the Classic GNOME Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28050/how-do-i-switch-to-the-classic-gnome-desktop)

Where I can restore the old look of Ubuntu 10, or get back the "start" panel? the new left sidebar is beauiful , but kinda hard to get quick access to applications cause i need to search every time the app name

Comment: You should rename your question to: "How do I restore the old look of Ubuntu 10.10?", for instance. Moreover, when you are using the default GUI of Ubuntu 11.04, try launching your application and then, in the dock on the left of your screen, right click and select "Keep in launcher".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Log out
2. Choose "Ubuntu Classic" from the session menu (at the bottom)
3. Log in

Comment: thanks to your message, i followed your clue and find out this : http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/linux-distributions/linux-distributions4-ubuntu/1540-top-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-1104-natty-narwhal (this have screenshots of how to do it)