# How do you uninstall Unity?

Tags: unity, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you remove Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity)

I've been trying to find out how to uninstall Unity for a couple days now and I really wish there was just an uninstall option somewhere... Please help!!!

Comment: I have nominate it to reopen. Uninstall is not the same than remove. All the answers of the other question tell how to remove but keep Unity installed, so they are not useful as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 5):

You can uninstall Unity via the Software Centre, *(Applications ➜ Ubuntu Software Centre)*. Type `unity` in the search box, select Unity and then select remove (see screenshot)

[image]

You will need to select all applications associated with Unity to remove it completely.

Comment: If you are in 10.04 you will do the same thing

Comment: Can you move this answer to the original question which this is now a dupe of? It's a good answer!

Comment: @Jorge - will do, just need to figure out how......