# how to uninstall unity in ubuntu 11.04, not disable it

Tags: 11.04, unity, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you remove Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity)

How can i uninstall or purge the unity desktop completely from Ubuntu11.04, **not disable it**, exactly remove it?