# How to remove unity and unity-2d?

Tags: unity, 11.10, unity-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you remove Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity)
>   [how to uninstall unity in ubuntu 11.04, not disable it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61775/how-to-uninstall-unity-in-ubuntu-11-04-not-disable-it)

I use gnome-shell, and I do not use unity or unity-2d, so I would like to remove those. Which packages do I have to remove to get rid of them (without removing packages I need for gnome-shell).

sudo aptitude remove ... ?

(please do not mark as duplicate of [How can you remove Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity), since this is another question, and the answer is not in there; this question is simpler and is about version 11.10)

Comment: This is still a duplicate of that question, I'll update it now.

Comment: Also, I do not just want to remove unity the package, but also a lot of unity deps, like unity-indicater etc.