# Can I remove Unity 2D safely?

Tags: unity-2d

My computer can run Unity 3D comfortably, and I don't really want Unity 2D as a fallback. Can I remove it without breaking my system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, and you'll save 205KB of diskspace. `sudo apt-get remove unity-2d`.

Comment: If i remove unity 2d Will I get update for it?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend it. What if your video card fails and you use an old spare part to get something done in a pinch, and it doesn't work with 3D right away? Or even just something goes wrong with configuration on a future update?

I suppose you can apt-get it again, but why the hassle?

Answer (score 2):

Of Course you can, just use `sudo apt-get remove unity-2d`.

**My Two Cents:**
This will not modify your Unity 3d as they are 2 different packages. But in my opinion failing of your default graphics card and id your alternate card(if any) wont work with 3d right away, you can use unity 2d. you *can* use `apt-get` again but why go through the waste of time? Besides it only takes 205KB of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Unity 2D and 3D are different packages. So it should not broke anything!

check this

[How to remove unity and unity-2d?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62004/how-to-remove-unity-and-unity-2d)