# Completely remove Unity and use gnome-shell instead

Tags: unity, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you remove Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity)

I really want to use Gnome-shell instead of Unity. But when i installed gnome-shell if found some interference from Unity in Gnome-shell desktop..

I want to use Gnome-shell as in Fedora or Arch, without any add-ons from Unity.

How to completely remove Unity without affecting my system ?

Comment: What interference are you talking about? There should be nothing from Unity in Gnome Shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to install from an Ubuntu minimal.iso and install gnome shell. After the base package is installed you will reboot to the terminal.  IIRC correctly it was pretty much just sudo apt-get install gnome-shell lightdm xorg gnome-tweak-tool.  Doing it that way is similar to doing a simplified Arch installation.