# Is it safe to uninstall Unity?

Tags: unity, 11.10, compiz, gnome

I'm running Oneiric on a really old laptop. Unity is very slow and sluggish, whilst Gnome-shell works perfectly.. oh so perfectly. This laptop has a pretty small HDD and I need to keep as much space free as possible. I've seen that it is possible to uninstall Unity and keen Gnome-shell, but how safe is this?

Will Ubuntu automatically stop downloading updates for Unity?
Will any other important packages be affected by the removal of Unity?
Which other packages will become redundant after removing Unity?

Comment: possible duplicate -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity

Comment: I don't want to know how to remove Unity. I want to know if it is safe to remove Unity...

Answer (score 1):

Yes perfectly safe (I accidentally did once and installed it back since I love unity)