# How To Replace Unity with Gnome Shell via Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: 11.10, unity, gnome

IMHO, Unity is just as productive and functional as Gnome Shell, and since for me, Gnome Shell looks a lot more stylish, I would like to replace Unity in Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome Shell.

**EDIT:** Without a further thought, I opened the Ubuntu Software Center > searched "Gnome Shell" and installed it. And since I use auto-login, Ubuntu logs-me-into Unity.

To prevent that...

- I want to uninstall Unity completely. How do I do that?
- After doing the above, Gnome Shell loads by default right?

Comment: if you are using autologin and you want to autologin to gnome-shell then use this question to guide you:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins/62836#62836

Comment: @fossfreedom Instead of doing that, I would love to uninstall Unity completely. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: yep - covered by this question and answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log out.

Then, in the lightdm greeter click on the gear symbol and click on "Gnome". This will load the gnome-shell desktop.

To set gnome-shell as default, open a terminal and type

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s gnome-shell
```

Comment: I know that. The thing is, I want Gnome set as default. How do I do that?

Comment: edited post and added info.

Comment: One last thing. Can you plz tell me how to uninstall Unity completely? (I edited my question to reflect the same) Thanks a lot by the way.

Comment: @BadLearner Removing Unity completely is a horrible idea - the site is covered in stories as to why this is a bad idea. If you'd join me [in the chatroom (link)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room), I'd be happy to explain why in further detail.

Comment: follow [these](http://linux-software-news-tutorials.blogspot.com/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-oneiric-remove-unity-and.html) instructions. I wouldn't recommend it though. Unity doesn't take much space on your disk, and unity has it's good points like the global-menu and the dash.

Comment: @severin last Q: How do I set Unity as default if I have to? Use this? `sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s unity-shell` ??

Answer (score 0):

It's been done. See this distro here:
http://ubuntu-gs-remix.sourceforge.net/p/home/
I'm using it and it works great!  Still I'm curious and a little worried about the ominous warnings mentioned above related to using Gnome 3 without Unity.  Hence I think I will install vanilla 12.04 LTS instead and add the Gnome 3 shell.