# Using Ubuntu Past Support Cycle

Tags: updates, mate, support

Hi I am new to linux in general but after trying way too many distro's i have found the one i like is the new Ubuntu Mate-Remix is the nice looks of ubuntu but without Unity which i do not like

Anyways the only reservation i have with using this is the fact that it has a short support cycle as it is not based off an LTS version now seeing as i have been told of how much more secure linux is over windows (which is why i am interested in using it) would it be ok to continue to use the version after that short support cycle has ended with windows you are forced to upgrade after support ends like in the case of Windows XP but i am wondering seeing as viruses are not really and issue like they are on windows can i continue to run it unsupported as long as everything is running well?

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with using MATE 1.6, you can use the `mate-desktop` package available in Ubuntu 14.04 to set up a MATE desktop. MATE 1.8 is not officially available, but can be installed using the following steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://repo.mate-desktop.org/archive/1.8/ubuntu trusty main"

wget -q http://mirror1.mate-desktop.org/debian/mate-archive-keyring.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mate-core mate-desktop-environment mate-notification-daemon
```

MATE 1.8 on Ubuntu 14.04 is known to be [buggy](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2223427).

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you don't like is Unity why not replace it with Gnome 3? It is simple and you will be able to make use of the latest version of Ubuntu.

[How To Replace Unity with Gnome Shell via Ubuntu Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81703/how-to-replace-unity-with-gnome-shell-via-ubuntu-software-center)