# Uninstall Unity without ubuntu-desktop and use Gnome Shell instead

Tags: 11.10, unity, gnome, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you remove Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity)

When I try to remove unity in Synaptic or Ubuntu Software Center it says that it want to remove ubuntu-desktop too which depends on all desktop applications. But I don't want to remove the whole desktop but only Unity. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link shows you how to remove unity

[How can you remove Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity)

You then install gnome-shell.

ubuntu-desktop is a meta package and can be removed safely.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages