# How can I remove and re-install Unity?

Tags: unity, software-installation, compiz, uninstall

Unity is misbehaving after installing GLX Dock - HUD does not open with GLX Dock turned off and there are ugly shadows in the panel, three control buttons (close, minimise, maximise) and *"Ubuntu Desktop"* label when there are no apps running. I have to click the top panel to get the <kbd>Super</kbd> key to open the Dash.

I have tried `unity --reset` and `unity --replace` commands, but they do not help.

Can I un-install and re-install Unity?

Comment: Does this Q&A help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/61776/156468 it's a old question

Answer (score 18):

This is what I used when I had a problem with it.

*These Commands Will Remove/Uninstall Compiz Unity:*

```
sudo apt-get remove compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get remove compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get remove compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get purge compiz*
```

*Then to Re-install Compiz Unity use:*

```
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop-2d
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install xserver-xgl
sudo apt-get install emerald
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: can you explain what you are doing, and why it works?

Comment: As you can see by the command line code in the "Use this to Remove/Uninstall Compiz Unity:" it is Uninstalling Compiz Unity, so if there was any bugs or Problems before hand it has now been wiped, so you can do a new install to fix the corrupted Compiz Unity files if it had a problem before.

Comment: You can combine those apt-get install and apt-get remove lines.

Comment: While reinstall I am getting the following error! Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-desktop-2d
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xgl
E: Unable to locate package compiz-fusion-plugins-extra