# Launcher icons invisible, still work in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher, icons

Rebooted my PC today to find that my launcher icons are not showing on the launcher bar, even though they are still there.  I can hover over the launcher bar and see (via the mouse tool-tip) that they are still there, and I can even interact with them.  I cannot, however, see them even after doing the following:

- Trying to reset unity via `unity --reset`
- Attempting to remove and re-install Compiz Unity via these instructions: [How can I remove and re-install Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131016/how-can-i-remove-and-re-install-unity).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried `unity --reset-icons`?

It's best to run this kind commands from tty1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>, log in and then enter these commands:

```
unity --reset-icons
unity --reset
reboot
```

Comment: I don't know which of the two additions made the difference (running `--reset-icons` and using tty1.  Either way, it fixed the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI, for me, rebooting fix this problem for a while, then it kept coming back.  `unity --reset-icons` worked for me only after upgrading the unity package using `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install unity`, and thankfully it didn't require a reboot.  Crossing my fingers this fixes it for good.

Answer (score 3):

The disappearing icons problem is described in [bug #806248](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/806248). You should mark the bug as affecting you.

Comment: Thanks, my `uptime` of "25 days, 22 min" would seem to indicate that this is the bug that I'm experiencing.