# Unity 3d Icons disappear after update

Tags: unity

After an update, the dock icons on unity 3d are gone. In 2d mode it's normal.

Now I don't know what to do. I already tried replace and reset commands, remove and install unity but nothing works for me.

Unity's bar is still there but there are no icons. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (3.4.0.-030400-generic)

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please see http://askubuntu.com/q/162854/35775

Comment: Try booting from older officially installed kernel  (3.2..) and see if that problem still persists

Comment: _"Please see askubuntu.com/q/162854/35775"_ : doesn't work Using.

Using officially installed kernel doesn't fix it.

Comment: Hello all.After last upgrade, my icons came back, but now my terminal crashed. It does not refresh after a 'ls' for example.
What should I do?

Comment: This unanswered question is about Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL. Furthermore problem went away on it's own after a regular update. VTC as `not reproducible`.