# broken `Launcher` after experimenting with `MyUnity` themes

Tags: launcher, themes, myunity

I used MyUnity to try some themes such as `clearlooks` and `industrial` and then I switched back to `default`.  Now my `Launcher` is broken.  How can I repair this?

There are many invisible items in the `Launcher`, such as shown here above the `Google Chrome` icon.

**Edit:** `unity --reset` results in thousands of error messages and warnings and the complete loss of the Launcher and top-of-screen task-strip.  The execution of this command might take 15 minutes or more.  `unity --reset-icons` also executes for at least 15 minutes, spews errors, and does not resolve the problem.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launcher icons invisible, still work in 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162854/launcher-icons-invisible-still-work-in-12-04)

Comment: This is not a duplicate because the fix at that link does not work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This procedure can fix it.

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall humanity-icon-theme`

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-icon-theme-full`

Then go to `System Settings > Appearance > Theme` and cycle between `Ambience` and `Radiance`, ending back at your preference.  Shutdown and reboot.

Install [this fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/806248) just in case it might prevent a re-occurrence of the problem.