# Launcher icons disappeared, how to get back

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Shortly after I installed, the launcher disappeared. It seems to be behind the desktop. After seeing the advice to press <kbd>alt</kbd>&<kbd>F2</kbd> together then type `reset icons` I did that and got `status on, status pending`. I still have no launcher icons. I don't know how to reduce the size of the desktop to see if the icons are indeed behind the desktop.

How can I get my launcher icons back?

Comment: I'm not sure [this is still relevant?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162854/launcher-icons-invisible-still-work-in-12-04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can access to a terminal window give this command:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

and after give this other one:

```
setsid unity
```

The first command resets the configuration to the defaults, and the second reloads unity.