# Failed to load session "ubuntu"

Tags: compiz, 12.10, session

I installed CCSM to enable window previews in Unity. But when I went into extras, there was no 'window preview' option.

So I tried experimenting with other options in Compiz and now there are no borders in the dialogue boxes (close, minimize, restore buttons are not there, I had enabled some 'flat....' option in Compiz.

Later, I uninstalled Compiz and then reinstalled it. Now it says

> "Failed to load session Ubuntu"

I can't even access through the guest account, I am new to Ubuntu.(please explain in detail).

All I have access to is the login screen (it still shows my custom wallpaper). Please help, I don't want to lose my stuff.

Answer (score 7):

I got the same problem ""Failed to load session Ubuntu"" when I was trying to login afer uninstall Compiz.

I tried to boot from USB with Live Ubuntu inside and others ways but it doensnt work.

At the end, it comes up with a simple solution.

1. Boot your Ubuntu as normal
2. When you see the log-in screen, try to Ctrl - Alt - F1
3. In my case (ubuntu 12.10), a blank screen appears. dont be panic, try Ctrl - Alt - F2
4. A login console shows up and ask you to login using your id and password.
5. After login. Run these commands. (tested)

`sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install unity-2d

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager

sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra

sudo apt-get update`

I got this above list of commands from [How can I remove and re-install Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131016/how-can-i-remove-and-re-install-unity)
but some doesnt work so I mentioned only good-running command in my case. 
I highly recommend to restart your system before try to login again.

`sudo shutdown -r now`

Hope it helps you to solve your problem.

Linh

Answer (score 5):

Open virtual console : Ctrl+Alt+F1

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

sudo apt-get install -f install

sudo dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-desktop

sudo reboot

Then try to login, This will bring back your desktop

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-desktop` did the trick for me, thanks!

Comment: Very good. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` did the job for me because I updated ubuntu OS

Comment: This had no effect for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me it seems to have been related to having a Cinnamon desktop installed that I was playing around with.  Once I removed it using [Failed to load session "ubuntu" - Ubuntu 13.10 on MacBook Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361314/failed-to-load-session-ubuntu-ubuntu-13-10-on-macbook-pro) everything was fine. ( I don't have a macbook pro, it was the same on my Dell desktop).

Comment: Same here. I removed cinammon as package, but a bunch of dependencies were still there. So I started removing cinammon-session, cinammon-desktop-data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into the LiveDVD and install Compiz. It's possible that you disable Unity. Update Unity.

Add the following PPA to your Software Sources per these instructions: `ppa:unity-team/staging`
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unity-team/staging`

After adding, open the 'Software Updater', click ‘Check for Updates’, and proceed to install those you’re prompted to do.

This can also be achieved via the Terminal by running:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Restart your computer.

Comment: I cant install compiz

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: there is no internet

Comment: i have booted in the live dvd just now

Comment: what i cant connect to the internet on that machine

Comment: Is it wired or wireless connection? BSNL toh nahi hai na, bhai?

Comment: You'll see a n/w sign between chat (letter-like logo) and volume/audio on top-right corner. Make sure n/w is enabled.

Comment: Enabled toh hai yarr, lekin mera wifi hai aur merko dlink ke drivers install karke network manager ko uninstall karna padega tab jaake chalega

Comment: koi repair option nahi hai livedvd mai ??

Comment: Bhai, thodi der ke liye taar (ethernet) ghused le na. Plus, wired n/w are generally faster than WiFi. Don't kill me if you're using an engg college WiFi.

Comment: Nah! Koi repair option nahi. 'Install Ubuntu' try kar fir repair possible hai. :-)

Comment: nai re engg coll mai wifi hi nahi hai(lol)

Comment: Okay. Waise enggr ho is liye is waqt jaag rahe ho. gtg, college tomorow. Kal dekhenge is pange ko. Don't worry, it'll work. Good luck.

Comment: Reinstall ubuntu 12.10 ka option disabled hai

Comment: Boot into the DVD, choose 'Try Ubuntu' and the from the session, run 'Install Ubuntu'. Should work, yaar.

Comment: working reinstalling it now thanks for the help :)

Comment: Aur Engineering(Mechanical) mai ghanta kuch sikha hai !!!!!!!!