# could not acquire name on session bus -> failed to load session ubuntu

Tags: unity, 13.04, login

I am running my system on a lenovo X1 since 12.10 and upgraded to 13.04 (months ago). Since today for now special reason (apart from the weekly system update from ubuntu) i can't login to unity desktop anymore.

I get a blank screen with two overlaping error messages:

1.) could not acquire name on session bus
2.) fail to load session ubuntu (with a button "logout")

I can still login to "gnome fallback".

What I already did was asking google. I found some stuff about my error 2 and i did the reinstall stuff  mentioned in here: [Failed to load session "ubuntu"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205872/failed-to-load-session-ubuntu)

For error 1.) I found some solutions which didnot fit to my case because i don't use VNC Server (i have a vnc client though).

Can someone please help me to fix this ?

Thank you very much.
Michael

Comment: so ... i did the upgrade to 13.10 today, hoping to solve my problem. unfortunately not. now the message 1 is diplayed for a part of a second or so , then it bounces me back to the login screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got exactly the same after upgrading to 13.10, and it was solved uninstalling Cinnamon which I had installed some months ago.

Check if you have alternative desktop installed (out of Gnome fallback), and remove it.
Note that for Cinnamon, I had to purge to make it works (removing was not enough) :

```
sudo apt-get remove cinnamon
sudo apt-get remove --purge cinnamon*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: mhmm ... thanks for your answer but I decided to reinstall my system from the scratch so I can't verify your answer anymore. But in my case I had installed Cinnamon too but I cant even remember that I did this. I just found out when my ubunut login stopped working. In my case the error occured already on 13.04 and did not go away during upgrade to 13.10