# Failed to load session "ubuntu" - Ubuntu 13.10 on MacBook Pro

Tags: login, 13.10, session, nouveau

I've installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my MacBook Pro 7, 1 and have run into difficulties. On my first reboot of this freshly installed system, I cannot log in to the default graphical session. After I log in from the login screen, I am briefly presented with the following error message:

> "Failed to load session "ubuntu"

Then, I am returned to the login screen.

When I look at /var/log/syslog, I see an awful lot of what appear to be nouveau-related errors.

How should I proceed?! Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the output of `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`?

Comment: I have been accessing the operating system simply via terminal interface (from Alt F2 at the login screen), so the response is "Error: unable to open display". I installed LXDE to run the test. When I run the test in this environment, the OpenGL vendor string is "nouveau", the OpenGL renderer string is "Gallium 0.4 on NVAF" and the OpenGL version string is "3.0 Mesa 9.2.1" while all of the checks report "yes".

Comment: Have you tried to install a proprietary driver (`nvidia-319`, for example)?

Comment: This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10, so it is using nouveau only. On previous occasions, I have tried earlier NVIDIA drivers have have usually found them to screw things up quite a bit. However, I'll try the latest efforts, as you suggest. Would there be any reason not to use [`nvidia-325`](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/linux-display-amd64-325.15-driver) (or, indeed, the 331 beta)?

Comment: Probably it would be safer to use the ones from the Ubuntu repositories (the most recent available is 319) instead of the ones available in the nVidia website. You can install it using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-319` and then reboot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a problem because I also had cinnamon installed on my system. I could login after removing cinnamon by running the following

> sudo apt-get remove --purge cinnamon*

and then

> sudo apt-get autoremove

Logout, and then login toNow it all works fine in default session.

Comment: This seems to have helped. I can log in now and interact with the default Unity interface. Unhappily, there are occasional freezes (requiring a power off) when using it. Would you have any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: More detailed answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/360878/73968

Comment: Thanks for your help. Removing Cinnamon-related infrastructure seems to have made the system much more stable.