# After deleting some apps I can't pass the login screen

Tags: unity, themes, login-screen

I have applied Mac OS X theme to my Ubuntu 13.10, and then got bored adn tried to revert it. Instead of trying to change themes first from the Unity Tweak tools, I tried to uninstall everything I could from the Application center (Not the things that come with Ubuntu itself). Not I can see my Log In screen and enter my password, but then nothing happens. It accepts my password (the bar dissappears) and it stays there forever. The Wi-Fi, turn off the computer buttons on the top right works. But the screen does not continue to my desktop.. It just stays there waiting in my Log In screen..

Note: Guest logging in does not work either..

Answer (score 1):

As it sounds like you have removed Unity (the Desktop Manager), reinstalling Unity should work.

Start your computer, and wait for the login screen.

Don't login in but, enter the tty with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

Then login and run:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-2d
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop-2d
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install xserver-xgl
sudo apt-get install emerald
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install git compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Then either reboot with:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Or return to the login screen and reboot.

It then should hopefully work. [image: smiley]

---

*As I am fairly lazy, I sourced the commands from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131016/how-can-i-remove-and-re-install-unity)*

Comment: Thank you! It worked, apperiently I can delete Unity from the Software Center App, without being notified by "this is important software, if you delete this you may not be able to get new updates" warning.

Comment: It wouldn't notify anyway, as Unity is just the interface, and there are many others anyway, like Gnome, KDE, LXDE, XFCE etc. Glad you got it sorted.