# Unity doesn't load ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04

I installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS with wubi and after 2 days of use after the login screen unity doesn't seem to load. Notifications work so the cursor but only the backgroun appears and nothing else. What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall your unity or reset it.

Few sites here:

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html

[How can I remove and re-install Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131016/how-can-i-remove-and-re-install-unity)