# Restore Ubuntu's default UI

Tags: restore

I recently switched over to Ubuntu 13.04, I used it on my Laptop it worked pretty great, then I updated it to 13.10 then further updated it to 14.04.

While upgrading to 14.04, my UI suddenly crashed - I don't know why. I installed gnome package using `sudo apt-get install gnome`, my UI worked but I didn't like that UI at all.

Is there any solution to restore Ubuntu's Default UI? I tried deleting `~/.config` files but that didn't work either?

Comment: Does `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` work?

Answer (score 3):

**You need to switch desktop environment at login. Logout (or reboot) to change it.**

[image]

**If the above doesn't work** (i.e. `Unity` is broken), reinstall `Unity`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and execute:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-fusion-plugins-extra compiz-plugins-extra
$ sudo apt-get purge compiz*
$ sudo apt-get install unity-2d ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-2d compizconfig-settings-manager xserver-xgl emerald compiz-fusion-plugins-extra git compiz-plugins-extra compiz-plugins-extra install unity
$ sudo reboot
```

([Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131016/how-can-i-remove-and-re-install-unity) for `Unity` reinstall)

You can remove `Gnome` as:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

If you don't reboot, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back.