# Dash doesn't show applications, only files

Tags: unity, unity-dash, search

I am fairly new to Ubuntu. I have 14.04 LTS installed and it used to work just fine. Since recently however, whenever I want to open an application, Dash doesn't show the application but just some files and irrelevant stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you opened the dash by hitting <kbd>Super</kbd>. However, this opens the home page of the dash which provides usually both files and applications as s search result.

You have to use the *Applications* lens to search for your programs. You can get there by opening the dash (hit <kbd>Super</kbd> or click on the Ubuntu symbol at the top of the launcher bar on the left side of your screen) and then clicking on the **A** symbol at the bottom of the dash.
Alternatively, you can use the keyboard to navigate between the lenses: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go right, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go left.

You can also directly enter the dash's application lens by right-clicking on the Ubuntu icon at the top of the launcher and selecting "Applications" in the context menu or by hitting <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> instead of <kbd>Super</kbd> only.

I hope this is what you looked for. Don't hesitate to accept the answer by clicking on the gray tick on the left if it solved your problem. Otherwise leave me a comment, please.

Comment: i used the applications lens but it already says "sorry,there is nothing that matches your search". and when i type in something, still nothing.

Comment: Did you do a reboot since the error occurred the first time? I had a similar issue once and it just vanished after a clean reboot. Always remember: **reboot = first aid**

Comment: yes, its been some weeks since this first happened

Comment: You could try to reset your Unity settings as described [there](http://askubuntu.com/a/202020/367990). Maybe even a reinstall of Unity/Compiz might be of use ([link](http://askubuntu.com/a/131090/367990)), but try this as last option before a complete fresh install of the whole system...