# Replace Unity with Gnome / Cinnamon

Tags: unity, uninstall, unity-2d, gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the Cinnamon Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop)

I have already installed Ubuntu 12.04 and now cannot reinstall Kubuntu Xubuntu etc.

I don't want Unity and its associated stuff at all.. How can i remove it from my install and then go for some other desktop. I tried installing gnome-shell but didn't liked that
Also somewhere i read that gnome is still more responsive than unity.

I would prefer to have Gnome or cinnamon instead. Folks please throw some light on the installation commands for the same.

Comment: ... and to remove unity: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity

Comment: and to install gnome-classic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remvove Unity

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d-places unity-2d unity-2d-panel unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-services unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-applications gir1.2-unity-4.0 unity-common indicator-sound indicator-power indicator-appmenu libindicator6 indicator-application evolution-indicator indicator-datetime indicator-messages libnux-1.0-0 nuxtools gnome-control-center-signon gnome-control-center-signon-autopilot
```

To Install Gnome

[image: Install via the software center]

To Install Cinnamon 1.4 in ubuntu

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Source: http://ubuntublog.org/how-to-remove-unity-desktop-in-ubuntu-12-04.htm