# Remove unity and install KDE?

Tags: 12.04, unity, kde

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you remove Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity)

How to fully remove Unity Desktop Environment and associated files and dependencies from Ubuntu 12.04 and have a pure KDE installation ?

Comment: 'a pure KDE installation' like any other "pure" stuff is 90% a temptation that should not receive excessive credit. Ubuntu is always Ubuntu no matter the DE, except if your main concern is limiting the use of resources. Just install `kubuntu-desktop` and do not bother about the presence of Unity. But if you really want a pure and hard KDE, make a complete new Kubuntu install from a cd/usb

Answer (score 7):

From the terminal: `sudo apt-get remove unity*` and then `sudo apt-get autoremove` so nothing stays, then proceed to Install KDE `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`.