# Window behavior problems after removing Unity

Tags: unity, gnome, gnome-classic

I just reinstalled Ubuntu 12.10 and ran

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-core
```

then

```
sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d unity-2d-panel unity-2d-shell
```

I have done this before and never had any problems but after chosing Gnome Classic and logging back in I noticed that I am unable to move windows such as Nautalis or Text Editor. These programs dock in the upper-left hand corner as usual but there is no way to drag and drop them or close them other than clicking close on the panel at the bottom.

I tried this with Gnome Classic No Effects and I can control the windows but they still do not look right. I can tell that I am missing some things. Should I install something like gnome-desktop or other components?

I just reformatted after really messing up Gnome due and no longer being able to run gnome-terminal so I don't want to break anything else. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a cool help which can guide you:

[How can you remove Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity)

To reset unity,
1. Install dconf-tools
2. Run this command in terminal: `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`
3. Run `unity --reset-icons`
4. Logout/Restart.

Enjoy Ubuntu. :)

Comment: Thanks, I saved that in a text file for next time. I turns out I needed to reinstall Compiz. I had tried apt-get ubuntu-desktop and it placed a lot of files but things still did not look right. I think I will also try apt-get autoremove --purge unity-* to clean up what was left behind in Unity.