# What desktop environment is this?

Tags: desktop-environments

I saw this picture in some question before. I tried searching for what desktop it is but I couldn't figure out. Does anyone know?

[image: desktop]

Comment: The desktop is unity. I'm trying to find the name of the theme right now.

Comment: !!! that's normal unity?!

Comment: Yes, but themed with a metalic theme.

Comment: wow! never thought it'd be unity because the dash button is small and the X _ [] are shifted to the left. ...so the theme is called "metalic"?

Comment: No, I don't know the theme's name

Comment: Unity but is is an OLD one (the dash button has since then moved to the launcher)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The desktop environment in that image, which you probably found in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/28535/145166), is Unity 5 (which was the Ubuntu 11.04 version) that had a smaller dash icon, as you can see in this image:

[image]

The highlight color was changed from the default orange to a light blue with a tool like ccsm or ubuntu-tweak-tool. Both of these can be found on the Ubuntu Software Center.

Also, a metacity (window decoration) metalic-looking theme has been installed. The buttons are the default unity ones.

Comment: ...I've been chasing it for quite some time because I thought of it as a lightweight desktop which is very similar to unity! turns out to be unity itself!! chase is over XD