# Can not log in to Desktop, but terminal works, Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: login, 14.10, lightdm

Yesterday I did `aptitude upgrade` and today when I enter my credentials I'm taken back to login screen, I can start my session by log in to console, and starting Xserver and unity manually.

I searched on google, tried to switch to GDM, but GDM starts in "Low graphics mode" and it seems I can't fix this either, also I tried to switch to proprietary nvidia drivers, but with no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a typo in my `/etc/profile` file...

Comment: I might suggest that you accept your own answer to close the question when you get a chance.

Comment: I was going to do that anyway, but I need to wait 48h

Answer (score 0):

### First, I would try repairing Unity using a script from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/202020/89515)

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

### If that doesn't work, I would follow [Mahesh's](https://askubuntu.com/users/45659/mahesh) advice and [try to reset gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56313/how-do-i-reset-gnome-to-the-defaults)

---

## If all else fails

I would recommend that you install a different desktop interface, such as KDE (picked because it exists in the main repositories).

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

If you are able to login to this, then uninstall Unity **(I have not tested this step)**

```
sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d unity-2d-panel unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-services unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-applications gir1.2-unity-5.0 unity-common indicator-sound indicator-power indicator-appmenu libindicator7 indicator-application indicator-datetime indicator-messages libnux-2.0-0 nux-tools libunity-misc4 unity-2d-common
```

Commands from https://askubuntu.com/a/20065/89515

Reinstallation should be easier, with `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`