# Ubuntu 18.04 running slow on vbox (Gaming PC)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, virtualbox, virtualhost

I have a gaming pc (windows 10) with:
GPU: 4 gb (nvidia GTX) 
CPU: 8 cpu's , 16 gb of ram (Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz)

To try to make ubuntu faster i've changed the settings of vbox so this are my current:

[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo 2]

[image: Photo 3]

[image: Photo 4]

What can i do to make it run smooth since i have a computer good enough for that?

Comment: Did you try enabling 2D and/or 3D acceleration?

Comment: No... i dont know if my ubuntu supports that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guest Ubuntu 16.04 runs very slowly in VirtualBox Windows 10 host](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775363/guest-ubuntu-16-04-runs-very-slowly-in-virtualbox-windows-10-host)

Comment: Have you tried installing the VirtualBox Extesion Pack that will allow you to install the virtual video drivers to help VirtualBox run faster?  https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads  Also, you will not achieve the same speeds running through a VM that you will running directly to the hardware due to virtualization.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in comments, I guess that the slow behaviour is related with graphics, not I/O or CPU related.

Try to enable 2D and 3D acceleration as both Windows 10 as VirtualBox host and Ubuntu 18.04 as guest work without issues with Nvidia GPUs.

Both options are shown at the bottom of your "Photo 4" menu.

And remember to install the 'guest additions' in the guest OS (Ubuntu) to make those changes working with:

[image: Installation of guest additions]

Comment: I've tested the 3d and the graphics look better and also faster! Thanks

Comment: If this answer fixed your problem, just pick it as the correct one. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like it was only at glance. Still buggy. On the beginning  it used to run smoothly , is it because now i have installed more apps and packages?

Comment: Those options does not install any package. Do you have the 'guest additions' installed in the guest OS (Ubuntu)?

Comment: Yes.. i've tested different configurations and definitely , the 3d makes the system more slow