# How to install kde and totally remove unity on ubuntu 14.04 lts?

Tags: 14.04, kde

I did not like unity desktop.I want to install kde desktop enviorment.Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Do `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`. Now login, and type in the Terminal/Console program:

```
sudo -i
```

Now insert your password, and let's now remove the Unity desktop:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge unity
```

DONE! If you're running 14.04, you will get KDE 4. If you're running 15.04, you will get Plasma 5.

Answer (score 0):

How about [`Kubuntu`](http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/)? Or you can use `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` to install KDE desktop, but I don't think this would be better than Kubuntu.

Comment: + http://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity